# rewrite small piece of python code

Tags: python, refactoring

I have lots of small pieces of code that look like:

```
for it in <iterable>:
  if <condition>:
     return True/False
```

Is there a way I can rewrite this piece of code with a lambda expression ? I know I can factor it out in a small method/function, but I am looking for some lambda thing if it can be done.

Comment: A lambda expression? Why? This seems like a premature optimisation to me. For loops are much more readable than a lambda is in Python as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the built-in [`any`  function](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/functions.html?highlight=any#any).

e.g.

```
any(<condition> for it in <iterable>)      # return True on <condition>
```

Comment: +1 because it's the only correct solution. Period. Why misuse list comprehensions when there's any and generator expressions?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what everyone else has said, for the reverse case:

```
for it in <iterable>:
  if <condition>:
     return False
return True
```

use all():

```
b = all(<condition> for it in <iterable>)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example which returns `True` if any of the objects in `it` is equal to `2`. by using the `map` function:

```
any(map(lambda x: x==2, it))
```

Change the lambda expression to reflect your condition.

Another nice way is to use `any` with a list comprehension:

```
any([True for x in it if x==2])
```

or alternatively, a generator expression:

```
any(x==2 for x in it)
```

Comment: You should leave those square brackets out. any/all work fine (better even since it short circuits) with generator expressions

Comment: A: Why do you write `any(True for x in it if x ==2)` instead of  `any(x == 2 for x in it)`?

Comment: @John - just another option, using list complrehensions

Comment: A: I was asking you to compare a baroque expression with a minimal expression, irrespective of whether it was in a list comprehension (yuk) or a generator expression.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to check the condition for every item of iterable you can use 
listcomprehensions to to this

```
b = [ x == whatever for x in a ]
```

you can combine this with any if you only need to know if there is one element 
that evals to true for your condition

```
b = any(x == whatever for x in a)
```